# To get the name of the series in bubble chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart

Below is my JSON Data for bubble chart.

```
{
 "chart":{"type":"bubble","plotBackgroundImage":"Image/bubble.jpg"},
 "plotOptions":{"series":{"dataLabels":{"enabled":true}}},
 "series":
  [
   {"data":[{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49,"name":"Task 2"}]},
   {"data":[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56,"name":"Task 4"}]},
   {"data":[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56,"name":"Task 3"}]},
   {"data":[{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21,"name":"Task 1"}]}
  ]
 }
```

I have reduced the data content for simplicity and below is my result..

I want to get the name of the concerned bubble to appear along with bubbles despite of series name and observed that numerical value of y is displayed on each bubble,don't want to have that numerical representation and also want to fix the background image in fix size. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

--------UPDATED QUESTION--------------

```
 string plotBackgroundImage = "Highcharts-3.0.7/graphics/Heatmap.jpg";
        var chart = new
        {
            type = ChartType,
            plotBackgroundImage

        };
        var dataLabels = new
        {
            enabled = true
        };
        var plotOptions = new
        {
            series = new { dataLabels = dataLabels }
        };
        var series = dataList;
        var obj = new { chart, plotOptions, series };
        string result = jSearializer.Serialize(obj);
```

and my JSON Data get stored in string as well as I pass this data directly to Highchart API to plot the graph, now How I am suppose to pass the formatter function can anyone please explain or any other way to achieve this target.

Answer (score 0):

Inside tooltip formatter you can access all the options with respect to that point.

I think It serves this case also.

here is a sample example.

```
tooltip:{
    formatter: function(){
        var name = this.point.options.name;
        return name + ' x : ' + this.x + " y: " + this.y
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Facing the acute problem here itself, I tried to use formatter but problem is I am creating my JSON data from WCF Service which I pass to create Highcharts Graph, now I don't know How I am suppose to create the function() so that it works after being converted into JSON...for detailed question,plz check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Use `tooltip.pointFormat`, which is patter for a tooltip, it has limited options, but point.name will work, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/bJtCt/

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{point.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y} EUR</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        valueDecimals: 2
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Short',
        data: [{
            x: 3, y: 15, name: 'test'
        }, {
            x: 5, y: 17, name: 'testing'   
        }]
    }]

});
```

Comment: No..it's not helping, actually I am not getting point.format inside point format..can you please check my updated question and show me how I should pass the pointformat into object to serialiaze it into JSON?

Comment: Use tooltip.pointFormat, not point.format. I don't know framework you are using on a server side, so I won't help you that way. I only can give you example how this should look like for Highcharts to work. And as you can see in live demo, it works.